# Objects children in Mongo get stored as different objects instead of under one object

Tags: javascript, mongodb

When I query a document that has arrays in them, it looks like:

```
{
    "profile_youtube_videos[sYi7uEvEEmk][thumbnail_url]":"https://i.ytimg.com/vi/sYi7uEvEEmk/mqdefault.jpg",
    "profile_youtube_videos[sYi7uEvEEmk][title]":"Bill Withers - Lovely Day (Original Version)",
    "profile_youtube_videos[sYi7uEvEEmk][video_url]":"https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=sYi7uEvEEmk"
}
```

Instead of, naturally, `profile_youtube_videos` being a key, then `sYi7uEvEEmk` being a children key of `profile_youtube_videos` and so on. Like how it's coming:

```
{sYi7uEvEEmk: 
    {
        thumbnail_url:"https://i.ytimg.com/vi/sYi7uEvEEmk/mqdefault.jpg",
        title:"Bill Withers - Lovely Day (Original Version)",
        video_url:"https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=sYi7uEvEEmk"
    }
}
```

I use mongo's `save(object)` function to save / overwrite documents.

```
db.users.save(user, function (err, response) {
  if (err) {
    return res.json(err);
  }

  return res.json(response);
});
```

Documents come in via a POST request, as well-working JS objects.
For example:

```
  $.ajax({
    url: 'example.com/users',
    type: 'POST',
    data: user, // good object
    // dataType: 'json', same result commented or not
    success: function (response) {
      // success all the time
      console.log('Save user via nodejs api response: ', response);
    },
    error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
      // just in case there's an error.
      console.log('Save user via nodejs api error response');
      console.log(textStatus, errorThrown);
    }
  });
```

Comment: did you noticed how your input is coming. i mean what is that you are feeding to the save method. i assume you are saving the input as-is hence what you see is what you saved.

Comment: is it possible can you extract the input document and paste it here

Comment: set the content-type to json. and everything should be set.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- Check POST parameters inspecting via browser.
- It should submit JSON.

use following code :

```
    $.ajax({
    type:"POST",
    dataType : 'json',
    url : 'example.com/users',
    data : JSON.stringify(json_data),
    contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
    success: function (response){ 
        var response = response;
      },
  });// close ajax
```